# JSR 303 ConstraintViolationException and detailed message

Tags: java, spring, validation, bean-validation, jsr

I have configured my `Spring Boot 1.5.1` application with `JSR 303` validation. Right now I'm getting `ConstraintViolationException` in case of wrong data.

Is it possible to get a detailed message(now it is null) about what was wrong(for example what field or method parameter violates constraints) with `ConstraintViolationException` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, your `ConstraintViolationException` has a set of `ConstraintViolation` objects. Each of them has the details that you want.

```
public static <T> String getValidationMessage(ConstraintViolation<T> violation) {
    String className = violation.getRootBeanClass().getSimpleName();
    String property = violation.getPropertyPath().toString();
    //Object invalidValue = violation.getInvalidValue();
    String message = violation.getMessage();
    return String.format("%s.%s %s", className, property, message);
}
```

With this I would get a message like, e.g "OrderLine.quantity must be greater than 0"